# Python/Django: What steps i have to follow in order to properly redirect a user with {{ next }}?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-authentication

For hours i'm trying to figure it out without result. `{{ next }}` variable is not working for me (i mean it is empty), but works this way `{{ request.REQUEST.next|urlencode }}`. However doesn't redirect me to the next location either with GET or POST. Can Django do that automatically or i have to manually write code inside each view?

I'm using DJango 1.3.

Here is a piece of my code:

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
LOGIN_URL = '/'
```

**login form**

```
{% load url from future %}

<form action="{% url 'user:login' %}" method="post">
        {{ form.username }}<br />
        {{ form.password }}<br />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.REQUEST.next|urlencode }}" />
        {% csrf_token %}
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**login view**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import auth
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = auth.authenticate(
                    username=form.cleaned_data["username"],
                    password=form.cleaned_data["password"]
                    )
            auth.login(request, user)

            #I added this piece of code in order to achieve the redirection
            #but i preffer a lot if Django could do it for me.
            next = request.POST.get('next', None)
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
        else:
            errors = form.errors.items()
            return render(request, 'base/homepage.html', {'form':form, 'errors':errors} )

    return redirect('base:homepage')
```

Thanks!

Comment: try request.GET.get('next')

Comment: How about you use the built-in `django.contrib.auth.views.login`?

Comment: auth.login is django.contrib.auth.views.login, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect from a template. You'll have to redirect from your view function that handles `'user:login'`.

To do that, use the [redirect shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) from django:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
   def your_user_login_view(request):
       #handle the form
       #if everything is all right:
       return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'.

This is used to override the login redirect location, by default when you login your are redirected to whatever you have in the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting ('/accounts/profile/' by default).

If you add a (hidden) field to the login form with the name "next" (by default) the value of the field will become the new redirect location, and you will be redirected there after the form validation is successful.

Having a fixed "next" value in your form can be useful but usually the common use case is to add a GET parameter to the login url, like this: http://example.com/my/login/url/?next=/loggedin/ and use this as the value for the next field value, allowing you to specify different next URL (for example redirecting the user to where he was before), this should be available in the template as {{ next }}, if that's blank probably you dont have a next GET param (no ?next=/next/url/ in the URL).

If after submitting you are redirected to the same form page then probably you have a form validation error, try adding {{ form.errors }} somewhere in your template to check this, maybe csrf check failure?

You can check this view here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L28-63

Comment: i don't have LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in my settings file but i'm using 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'. So the 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' is overriding LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL? My problem is that the redirect doesn't work either with GET or POST and for POST the {{ next }} value is empty. As you mentioned the GET parameter works like www.example.com/login/?next=/loggedin/ but eventually (after successful login) doesn't redirect me! (no errors in the form). Thanks.

Comment: No it's not overriding anything those are separate things, it you don't override that setting (LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL) on your settings.py file then the default django value ('/accounts/profile/') will be used.

Comment: @JorgeCode: So you submit the form and then what happens? You don't get redirected at all and you are still in the login form? How are you checking you are being successfully logged in?

Comment: I'm login in but the page redirects me to the index and not to the ?next=... I'm cheching if the user is authenticated like this in template: {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}...

Comment: the code in my post above is working but i'm doing the process manually. I mean that i'm checking the POST/GET manually for the "next" variable and then i redirect to the page...

Answer (score 0):

you have to put condition in your login view

```
{% load url from future %}

<form action="{% url 'user:login' %}" method="post">
        {{ form.username }}<br />
        {{ form.password }}<br />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" />
        {% csrf_token %}
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>


def login(request):
    if request.POST:
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],
                            password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if request.POST['next']:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:home'))

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: i submitted some fixes to your code. Please don't get offended or so but i know how to do this. I would like to know if it's possible to do that django itself and not me manually. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCode That's ok I'm not offended, you have the right to modified my codes the way you want it. It's just a quick answer. :)